# Python/BeautifulSoup script returning no results in CSV

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm new to python (and coding in general) and am trying to write a script that will scrape all of the `<p>` tags from a given URL and then create a CSV file with them.  It seems to run through okay, but the CSV file it creates doesn't have any data in it.  Below is my code:

```
import requests
r = requests.get('https://seekingalpha.com/amp/article/4420423-chipotle-mexican-grill-inc-s-cmg-ceo-brian-niccol-on-q1-2021-results-earnings-call-transcript')

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
results = soup.find_all('<p>')

records = []
for result in results:
    Comment = result.find('<p>').text
    records.append((Comment))

import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(records, columns=['Comment'])
df.to_csv('CMG_test.csv', index=False, encoding='utf-8')
print('finished')
```

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: first you could use `print()` to see what you get in `records`. Maybe it is empty so there is no data to save in file. Modern pages uses JavaScript to add elements and `requests`, `BeautifulSoup` can't run JavaScript so you should check what you get in `r.text` or you should turn off JavaScript in web browser and reload page to see what you can get without JavaScript.

Comment: The content on the page you linked is not present in the initial source; it's loaded in via JavaScript. `requests` is a pure HTTP client, and `BeautifulSoup` is a pure HTML parser. Neither support the interpretation/execution of JavaScript. As such this is a duplicate of [Web-scraping JavaScript page with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049520/web-scraping-javascript-page-with-python)

Comment: it has to be `soup.find_all('p')` without `< >`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to pass CSS selectors to BeautifulSoup methods. `<p>` isn't a selector. `p` is. So, in order to find all p tags, you need to use the `find_all` method on the soup like so:
`results = soup.find_all('p')`

[Take a look at this page for more info on the CSS selectors.](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)

Secondly, in your iteration over results, you don't need to *find* the tag all over again. You can simply extract the text by `result.text`.
So, if you rewrite your code like the following:

```
import requests
r = requests.get('https://seekingalpha.com/amp/article/4420423-chipotle-mexican-grill-inc-s-cmg-ceo-brian-niccol-on-q1-2021-results-earnings-call-transcript')

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
results = soup.find_all('p')

records = []
for result in results:
    Comment = result.text
    records.append(Comment)

import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(records, columns=['Comment'])
df.to_csv('CMG_test.csv', index=False, encoding='utf-8')
print('finished')
```

You'll find your csv well-populated with the content you're looking for.

Comment: I don't believe `find_all` takes CSS selectors though it can match on CSS values.